# How to create an animation that is active to visit the page

Tags: jquery, css, visited

What code should I add jquery to create an animation that is activated when a user visits the page.

Comment: If you add it on the $(document).ready() it will be executed everytime the user enter to the page also see this to work with animations https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ID").animate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add the function into the `<BODY>` tag using onload?

Like:

```
<BODY onload="myfunction()">
```